# Error when trying to use the Cardslib library: unable to find attribute android:foregroundInsidePadding

Tags: android, android-library, cardslib

When trying to implement the `Cardslib` library in my app, I get this error every time I try to run the app:

> ERROR: In  ForegroundLinearLayout, unable to find
>   attribute android:foregroundInsidePadding

However, upon looking through the `attrs.xml` file for the library, I found the `ForegroundLinearLayout` and that attribute is there. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue comes from the requirement of upgraded build tools, just as referred [here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/issues/444).

In my case all I needed was change in `build.gradle` from.

```
...
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
...
```

To

```
...
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
...
```

If you are using Android Studio and you don't have latest build tools installed, you will be prompted with wizard that can install it automatically.